# Exporting VM/vAPP in vCloud environment

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli, esxi, vcloud-director-rest-api

We have a customised vCloud environment. We are trying to download the vAPP image as ovf file for migrating it to some other environment. I am following this procedure

1. Stop the VM.
2. Click on download button on setting
3. It asks for download location and type of image (ova/ovf).
4. It initiates the download.

Now my problem lies on 4th step. When I click download it initiates download and I could see "enabling download" when it happened. After some unknown time(can't predict the time may be 2hr, 3hr 4hr, 1hr) the process gets failed. I have to repeat the process multiple times(at least 3 to 5 times) to start the actual download process where it actually copies the VM image on disk.

I am not able to predict the actual time of VM download and why the process get failed many time before it start the actual export process.

Can someone tell me answers of below mentioned questions

1. Does vCloud enable download functionality before it allows us to download the VM? If it does how much time it takes for this functionality to enable.
2. Can we enable this functionality beforehand so that vCloud should just start the VM download process instantly once I shutdown the machine and start the VM export process?
3. Do you think using CLI tool like ovftool will make the process faster and prevent it from failing so that I will get to know the actual VM download time and we can prepare a plan for migration?

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding of working with the API and SDK, I do not think 1 is possible... if it is... it's not straightforward.. at least to me

as for #3 if you are not using the CLI for scripting and automating purposes, yes it would definitely help

Comment: Thanks @A.Zia, let me try using CLI for this purpose.